# Maven Eclipse Plugin Does not Work with VPN

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, vpn

I am trying to run commands like Maven build or install in Eclipse via Maven plugin, and my environment is VPN'ed in. If I do, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.project.package:my:project:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at <some SQL library>:jar:xx.x: Failed to read artifact descriptor for <some SQL library>:jar:xx.x: Could not transfer artifact <some SQL library>:jar:xx.x from/to central ( **https**://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]
```

For those SQL libraries (DB2), since I couldn't resolve the dependencies, I had manually copied them into their respective .m2/... folders from another project.

The strange thing is that when I get off the VPN, maven build/install work just fine!

If the issue is related to the lack of availability of those DB2 libraries in Maven repository, is there a way to prevent Maven from attempting to downloading them?

Comment: Probably the network on your VPN doesn't allow to connect to the maven repository.

Comment: I would presume you are correct. If so, my question is how can I configure my settings.xml to connect to Maven's HTTP server?

Comment: Did anyone find any solution? I need it badly